# Is it possible to get an email address of user whose account is being accessed using OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, hotmail

I use OAuth2 authentication to gain access to the user's mail to Gmail (and Hotmail) using IMAP.
For this purpose I implemented the following steps:

1. Prompts the user email address.
2. Generate authorize url and open it in the embedded browser.
3. Gmail asks for email address and password from the user, and the rights required for my application.
4. Get access token, and the refresh token.
5. Form bearer token, using the email address, obtained in step 1, and access token, obtained in step 4.
6. Then I use AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2% bearer_token% to get access to user's mail.

This works fine. But I do not like that the user has to enter email address twice - on 1 and 3 steps. In fact, the user can enter different email addresses on step 1 and 3 so I receive "Invalid credentials" on step 6.

So the question is: is it possible to get an email address of user whose account is being accessed? Then I can skip the step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Google Identity Plateform, you can authenticate the user by adding the "openid" and "email" scopes to your authorization request (see [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters)).
When you will receive your access token, you will also receive an ID Token that contains the email of the user.

Using those scopes, you can get rid of the step 1. and retrieve the email at step 4 "Get access token, **ID token**, and the refresh token."
Details to validate the ID token are [on this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken)

Comment: Than you, @Spomky. Just one note: "openid" scope is not required, "email" is enough.

Answer (score 0):

As @Spomky wrote, for Google we can use the additional scope "email" to get id token and extract an email address from it.

For Hotmail(Live.com) we can make an additional request after step 4:
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN